# Express app crashing in vs code vs real-world project

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, visual-studio, express

so here is the question, when I am testing my route in postman, I make mistakes on purpose to handle the errors, for example, I know the email is already taken but I test it and get an error that the email already exists...
when I try to enter the correct information, every time I click send in postman, it does not do anything, and I have to go back to vs code which there is an error there:
Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
I have to resave it again in vs code, so I can test the route again in postman
now my question is in real life when I deploy my application to the host....when the user tries to register with an email that already exists, what will happen? the app will crash as well like in VS code or in the real server is different?

Comment: `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` this error occurs when you are trying to set a response header or send a response more than once. to fix this you need to `return` the response. and add some code it will help to understand where you are missing.

Comment: Are you using nodemon?

Comment: yes, I am using nodemon